# Jhipster create a multivaled field with mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb, jhipster

I want to create an entity with a multivalued field. I'd like to create a json array like this:

```
{ "singleField" : "value" , "multivaluedField" : [ "value1", "value2"]}
```

In java I'd like to create an arrayList or over Collection type.

As there is no relationship with a mongo project, how is it possible?